# multiple sessions are opened for one visitor

Tags: php, session

LAMP test server - only I am visiting it:

I have a website and for some reason I get multiple sessions per user (browser).  I am browsing the page with one browser only and I get 5-6-7-8 session files in /tmp. What can be the reason for it?

Sessions are simple file based sessions. I noticed that I get multiple sessions when I update a session variable (current page # is stored in $_SESSION['pagepos']). Updating a session variable for the current user should update the session file and should not create a new session file, right? My session id in the browser remains the same.

Thanks,
Hamlet

Comment: I am not sure it is related to the pagepos session. There are also ajax calls on the page

Answer (score 0):

If you use flash that requests something from the server (xml/other swf files), then it probably doesn't send any cookies with it and thus - new session is started with each request.

Comment: no flash on the site I removed ajax as well for testing, didn't help

Comment: then its either
1. some browser plugins
2. server proxy

Try debugging it by adding some test.php, adding mail() function there that would email you each time script is executed, and then opening this page with clean browser

Answer (score 0):

A session being created anew every time would make me think that the session cookie is refused by the browser. Check what cookies you take on board (I use [Firecookie](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6683), but there are many such extensions for the 'fox).

It happened to me once, and in the end I found I should have left `session.cookie_domain` commented out in my `php.ini`

Comment: Commented this out, but didn't help. I removed Google adsense, analytics, flash from the page, but it still happens (not every new page, but for approx every second click I get a new session file)

Comment: Well, this cuts out any simple explanation. The only thing that comes to my mind might be a very short session timeout.
Also, try with a different browser - just to make sure the problem is server-side...
If nothing else helps I'd suggest looking directli at the HTTP headers to see when exactly there is a new session (with Fiddler - http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp or LiveHTTPHeaders - http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp).
The last - and most foolproof - idea would be to install XDebug, debug the code stepping thru it one line at a time while keeping a window open ->

Comment: -> on the session file folder. Thus you might see exactly at what step a new session file is created

Comment: Whoops! The link to LiveHTTPHeaders is https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829

Answer (score 0):

I would check to make sure your AJAX calls are using the same session name.  Sometimes you need to add the session name in form post or get data.